# Can OpenCV be downloaded & built for Angstrom (BeagleBoard) not as part of the toolchain?

Tags: opencv, cross-compiling, beagleboard, toolchain, angstrom-linux

Simple question: can I build OpenCV on Angstrom (BeagleBoard) without downloading it as part of the toolchain ? meaning by downloading the code of the Unix version and building it

(of course, the build process itself would have to be done via the toolchain, but do I ***have*** to download the OpenCV ***as part of the toolchain*** rather than later, as separated files) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download OpenCV source code and use the toolchain to compile it. You might have to do some patching yourself, but [you wouldn't be first to succeed](http://buntyke.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/installing-opencv-on-beagleboardfrom_29.html).

Comment: link dead :( still searching for a comprehensive guide